# Подсветка определенных дат в jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: jquery, javascript, ui, html

Необходимо подсветить список заранее заданных дат (допустим, праздников) на jQuery UI datepicker. Стандартных способов не нашел. Это вообще возможно сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение - метод beforeLoad делает то, что мне надо